# vba code works well in 'Normal' view but dosen't work in 'slideshow' in powerpoint 2003

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a presentation with 6 slides. Slide 5 contains vba / macro  codes for rotatechart, change angle etc., The codes work well thru' vba editor 'RUN'in active document.(.ppt) but when put in 'Slideshow" mode codes don't work. Dbug msg: "Invalid request. no active document present". Pl help with code.

```
Sub MoveItInSlideShow()
  With SlideShowWindows(1).Presentation.Slides(5).Shapes("Picture 2")
      ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("Picture 2").Select
      Application.Run "'Hora.ppt'!Slide7.CreateSpirograph"

  end with
end sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Which version of PowerPoint are you using? That will help me to understand what your options are.

Answer (score 0):

This line is unnecessary, since you've already set a reference to the shape in the With statement previous:

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("Picture 2").Select
```

But since you can't select anything in slideshow view, any attempt to .Select anything will cause an error, which is probably what you're seeing.

If the code here requires a selected shape, you'll need to rewrite it:

```
Hora.ppt'!Slide7.CreateSpirograph
```